# Scheduled task on secured application not firing

Tags: grails, spring-security, scheduled-tasks

I have a method in a Grails (Grails version: 3.2.2) service with this cron expression:

```
@Scheduled(cron="0 0 0 ? * ?", zone="Europe/Madrid")
```

But it doesn't fire if I am not logged in the application.
The securization is made with Spring Security plugin.

Is there any way, whom doesn't include removing the securization of the controller, to fire it?

Comment: please mention Grails version. I have several cron jobs running along with SprinSecurity in Grails 2.5.2/3.1.7/ 3.3.0/ 3.3.1 with no problem. If possible also provide the Job class.

Comment: Grails 3.2.2, how do you do it along with SpringSecurity @devbd

Comment: btw, as you mentioned "removing the securization of the controller", did you fire any controller method in your cron job? I will come back to you with Grails 3.2.2

Comment: I have the scheduled task in a Service, but it does not fire. @devbd